# "Readers" and "audience" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two tags: [readers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readers) and [audience](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience). The tag wiki for [audience] reads "Those for whom one writes". A.k.a "readers". [readers] is the more popular tag, but it has no tag wiki at all.

Should we perhaps merge those two tags? I don't see any difference between them.

I would keep "audience" as the main tag, since it encompasses media other than literature: viewers of films and TV series, theatre audiences, players of videogames... Perhaps "readers" could be kept as a synonym, since it's so popular.

Comment: I'm catching up after my trip and saw this.  I agree with merging them but, looking at the tags, it seems this hasn't happened yet.  What is the next step to jumpstart this process?

Comment: Donno. Ask @MonicaCellio.

Answer (score 6):

The wiki excerpt for [readers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readers) says: "Issues that specifically target readers, marketing to particular sets of readers".  Whoever wrote that didn't seem to mean [beta-readers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-readers), for which there's a separate tag with a brief excerpt.

I agree that [audience](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience) is the better tag.  [readers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readers) currently has 93 questions.  Could somebody skim through them (I mean titles and the brief excerpts on the Questions page; I'm not asking anybody to read them all) and take note of any that somehow *aren't* about the audience?  We're looking for questions about beta readers and maybe advance review copies (ARCs).  After this sanity check, a moderator can merge the tags.

I guess we should create the synonym so this doesn't happen again.  If we do that, let's make sure the wiki excerpt points out the existence of [beta-readers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-readers).

Comment: Skimmed over the questions tagged [tag:readers]: went over all the titles. The only one that stood out as not fitting under [tag:audience] is https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/26782/14704 about how to make a book re-readable.